# SQL Query to a Column with ID Numbers Separated by Commas?

Tags: php, mysql

**The Script:**

```
<?php

    include("connect.php");

?>
<?php

    echo "<h1>The Hashtag: </h1>";
    if(isset($_GET['hashtag'])){
        echo $_GET['hashtag'];
    }


    // Select the ID of the given hashtag from the "hashtags" table.
    $tqs = "SELECT `id` FROM `hashtags` WHERE `hashtag` = '" . $_GET['hashtag'] . "'";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr);

    // This prints e.g.:
    // 100
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    print_r($row['id']);

    // Select the threads from the "thread" table which contains the hashtag ID number.
    $tqs_two = "SELECT * FROM `thread` WHERE `hashtag_id` IN ('" . $row['id'] . "')";
    $tqr_two = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs_two) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    $row_two = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr_two);

    echo "<br/><br/>";
    print_r($row_two);

?>
```

The script should select the rows by that ID number of the hashtag. It should look in the "hashtag_id" column of the table and see if that ID number can be found there, if it can be found there, then it should select that row.

The ID numbers are inside that "hashtag_id" column separated by commas.

**Example:**

```
98, 99, 100
```

Basically, is there a way to do a SQL query to see if the column ***"contains"*** that ID number or may have to something else here?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `$tqs = "SELECT id FROM hashtags WHERE hashtag = '" . $_GET['hashtag'] . "'";` shouldn't `hashtag` be `hashtag_id`?

Comment: Unrelated: $tqs is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: It is the "name" of the hashtag which is coming from the GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do **contains** you would use `LIKE` -

```
$tqs_two = "SELECT * FROM `thread` WHERE `hashtag_id` LIKE '%" . $row['id'] . "%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jay says, you can use "contains". You'll need to be cautious though; if you are looking for a hashtag_id of "9", your query needs to avoid returning "19", "99", "93", etc. To that end, you have rely on the exact formatting of the data in that hashtag_id field. If your numbers are really separated by commas and spaces, you can easily find exact matches that ARE NOT AT THE BEGINNING OR END of the query by doing "hashtag_id LIKE '%, 9,'". That won't, however, find any at the beginning or the end of the hashtag_id field. To catch those, you ALSO need "hashtag_id LIKE '9, %'" and "hashtag_id LIKE '%, 9'".

So, to catch all three possibilities:

```
SELECT * FROM `thread` WHERE `hashtag_id` LIKE '9,%' or `hashtag_id` LIKE '%, 9,%' or `hashtag_id` LIKE '%, 9';
```

Comment: There might be a way to make that more succinct, but I'm terribly sick at the moment and can't concentrate long enough to figure it out.

Comment: Also, I would suggest creating an entirely separate table for storing the relationship between hashtags and threads. It makes your hashtag searching simpler, probably faster, and should more easily accommodate tag maintenance (removing tags, &c).

Comment: Sorry for this question, though I thought this may be the way to do it. Do you have an example?